# What's another word for "Deploy" that conveys a similar meaning?

Tags: vocabulary

What's another word for "Deploy" that conveys a similar meaning?

**deploy**: *To move troops or equipment into position.*

I'm trying to come up with a name for a service where drones will be used to inspect factories and power stations.

I wanted to call it DroneDeploy, but that name is already taken by another drone service.

Is there a similar word that would be suitable?

Comment: Maybe if we understood why *deploy* doesn’t work for you, we’d be able to come up with something.  We also need to know the exact context in which you intend to use this word.

Comment: Position? Send?

Comment: It seems like *deployment* is just an incidental action necessary to accomplish your real objective- to inspect.

Comment: [Obligatory mechanization SNL skit.](https://view.yahoo.com/show/saturday-night-live/clip/7582059/robot-repair)

Comment: @Jim That's a good point, I'll post another question for "inspect"

Comment: This site shouldn't be used to provide a list of synonyms—you can easily use a thesaurus for that. Unless you have a *specific* English-related question, this seems off topic. (The fact that *drone* "is already taken" isn't a good reason for it being an inappropriate English word.)

Answer (score 1):

In military jargon, you might try the term "[infil](http://www.brassringfitness.com/terminology/)."  It means "infiltrate."  When you send in troops and/or equipment, you "infil."  When you recall troops or equipment, you "exfil."

Another word you might consider is "dispatch."

Comment: Here is a source for *exfil* -- feel free to add this to your answer if you think it would strengthen your answer.

Comment: @aparente001: You seem to have forgotten to post the link.

Comment: @Scott - Oops, you're right.  However, if Billy wants to strengthen his answer by citing wikipedia, it would not be difficult to retrace my steps.